# fade animation on a slider not working (CSS3 and html5 only)

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in CSS3 and HTML5, and right now I'm trying to create a HTML5 and CSS3 website in order to code a PSD mock-up.

The problem came once I started with the slider. Normally it should be a carousel slider with 2 images, a progress bar in the bottom and an animation to make it work in a loop.

So, first I have created a main div with two other divs inside containing radio inputs, that way I could get the next and previous arrows working in order to pass from one slide to another.

Then, in my css file, I've created the @keyframes with the opacity effect to proceed with the fade animation. Unfortunately this is not working as I thought, just the arrows but not the fade animation.

Could someone help me and have a look at my code? I'll really appreciate it!

HERE IS MY HTML5 CODE:

```css
@keyframes click{
0%{ opacity:.4;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes fade{
0%  {opacity:1}
45% { opacity: 1}
50% { opacity: 0}
95% {opacity:0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade2{
0%   {opacity:0}
45% { opacity: 0}
50% { opacity: 1}
95% { opacity: 1 }
100% { opacity:0}
}


 
#i1, #i2{ display: none;}

.slider{
width: 100%;
height: 550px;
margin: 20px auto;
position: rela
}

#first, #second{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
      
.previous{
width: 35px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
top:40%;
left:0;
background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70,0.6);
border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
}

.next{
width: 35px;
height: 70px;
position: absolute;
top:40%;
right: 0;
background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70,0.6);
border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover{
transition: .3s;
background-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 1);
}

.fas.fa-chevron-left{
position: absolute;
left : 0;
top: 30%;
margin-left: 5px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-right{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 30%;
margin-right: 5px;
color: white;
font-size: 30px;
}


.slider div#first {
background: url('img1.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
animation:fade 30000s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation:fade 30000s infinite linear;
}

.slider div#second{
background: url('img2.jpg') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
animation: fade2 30000ms infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: fade2 30000ms infinite linear;
}

.slide{z-index:-1;}

#i1:checked ~ #first,
#i2:checked ~ #second
{z-index: 10; animation: click 1s ease-in-out;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" id="i1" name="images" checked />
    <input type="radio" id="i2" name="images" />
    <div class="slide" id="first">
      <h1>WEBAGENCY: L'AGANCE DE TOUS <br> VOS PROJETS !</h1>
      <p>Vous avez un projet ? La WebAgency vous aide à les realiser !</p>
      <label class="previous" for="i2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></label>
      <label class="next" for="i2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="slide" id="second">
      <label class="previous" for="i1"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></label>
      <label class="next" for="i1"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label> </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is pretty clever. It seems like it works as intended when you load functioning background image urls in https://jsfiddle.net/n3a1ab5z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it's possible to combine:

- Progress in the bottom
- Working buttons on the sides
- Auto-advance

Just using CSS/HTML. You need to store your state as radio buttons, but if you advance using a linear animation, what will happen if the user wants to go back? How do you synchronize the state?

You CAN have both progress and working buttons. I have made an example based on your code on how to achieve that, with ability to add 2+ slides.

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.slider__slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

.slider__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: IndianRed;
}

.slider__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: Cornsilk;
}

.slider__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: PaleTurquoise;
}

.button {
  width: 35px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);
}

.button--previous {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
}

.button--next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 1);
}

.radio:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .slider__slide:nth-of-type(1),
.radio:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .slider__slide:nth-of-type(2),
.radio:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .slider__slide:nth-of-type(3){
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.progress {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 175px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.progress__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.radio:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .progress .progress__item:nth-of-type(1):before,
.radio:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .progress .progress__item:nth-of-type(2):before,
.radio:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .progress .progress__item:nth-of-type(3):before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;  
  content: '';
  background: black;
}


.fas.fa-chevron-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <input id="i1" class="radio" name="images" type="radio" checked />
    <input id="i2" class="radio" name="images" type="radio" />
    <input id="i3" class="radio" name="images" type="radio" />
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <h1>FIRST SLIDE</h1>
      <p>First Subtitle</p>
      <label class="button button--previous" for="i3"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></label>
      <label class="button button--next" for="i2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <h1>SECOND SLIDE</h1>
      <p>Second Subtitle</p>
      <label class="button button--previous" for="i1"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></label>
      <label class="button button--next" for="i3"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__slide">
      <h1>THIRD SLIDE</h1>
      <p>Third Subtitle</p>
      <label class="button button--previous" for="i2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></label>
      <label class="button button--next" for="i1"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
      <label class="progress__item" for="i1"></label>
      <label class="progress__item" for="i2"></label>
      <label class="progress__item" for="i3"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi,  thank you for your the answer! the problem is that I am working on a psd mockup and I have to get it done as much as possible like the original one. There are only two sliders and we just can see the slider the bar in the bottom going forward not showing the radio buttons.

Comment: Why don't use Javascript?

Comment: Lol, that's the challenge actually!

Comment: Otherwise, I could do the same thing but with an slide effect instead of a fade effect, but I can't get this done either